# Web Audio API not loading in Firefox 59

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, web-audio-api

I have written a code in ReactJS front end to play an audio file. It was working earlier but now I have hit some error and not able to troubleshoot it. I was hoping if somebody can give some advice.

I am using Firefox 59. And below is the error

[image]

And this is the error I get in the console in Google Chrome 65.0

[image]

Below is the code for playing the audio file with an onClick event.

```
    // Container component for Audio component

import AudioComponent from './audio';
import React from 'react';

class AudioPlayer extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.TogglePlay = this.TogglePlay.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            playsong: false,
            audio_file: "./sampleaudio.mp3"//this.props.src
        }
    }

    audio = new Audio();

    TogglePlay(){

        this.setState((prevState, props)=>({
            "playsong": !prevState.playsong
        }));

        if (!this.state.playsong) {
            this.audio.play();
        }
        else{
            this.audio.pause();
        }

    }

    componentDidMount(){

        this.audio.src = this.state.audio_file;
        this.audio.crossOrigin="anonymous"

        console.log('I am here 123456');
        console.log(this.state.audio_file)


    }

    render (){

        const props = {
            onClick:this.TogglePlay
        };

        return (
        <div>
            <AudioComponent {...props} />
        </div>
        )

    }

}

export default AudioPlayer;
```

Comment: `./somePath` is not a valid path in a browser context. The browser can not directly access the file system. A path relative to the current location would be  just `sampleaudio.mp3`. An absolute path would be `/sampleaudio.mp3`.

Comment: The problem still persists!

Comment: If you enter `localhost:3000/sampleaudio.mp3` in your browser what do you get? Your server seems to serve a file that contains html. Your player of course can't handle html. Is it maybe a 404 page?

Comment: Lol.. I just noticed one thing.. I had kept this in a non-public folder in the project! When I shifted the file to public folder both the code and your method of localhost:3000/sampleaudio.mp3 started working! How do we store this in private folder where it is not accessible for the public and play it upon request?

And by the way both ways work: audio_file: "./sampleaudio.mp3" and audio_file: "sampleaudio.mp3"